# How to load only a specific variable from another php file?

Tags: php, include

In a maintenance script for a web server, I need to get the database settings for each website/application on that server. As most of the websites are based on Drupal, the main settings file is settings.php, within that file various variables (such as $database) are defined, but sometime it also contains ini_set() statements for that specific site.

The script could include the settings.php to obtain the database setting but then the script will throw errors such as

`Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in include() (line 123 of /path/to/website/sites/default/settings.php).`

**Is there a way to only load (specific) variables from an included php file?**
Of course, I mean something smooth. I know, I could load the file into a string, use regex to extract the database variable and eval() that, but I'd rather think there is a better way.

Comment: The sanest thing would be to put those variables into a third file which you `include` in both files where it's needed.

Comment: That is true. But I do need to read out the settings from various different systems (Drupal, LimeSurvey, CodeIgniter, custom systems) and there are 100+ installations in total. For the custom sites this is truly an option (actually is set up this way) but for predefined systems such as Drupal I'd like to have a solution where I do not need to change the installation routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just including the settings.php (due to errors with `ini_set()` commands inside the included file I had to read the file into a string, get the desired part and `eval()` that.

In the example below, I am searching for the database settings inside a standard Drupal settings.php

```
#include $settings_path; // critical due to ini_set() commands.

$settings = file_get_contents($settings_path); // load file into string
$settings = preg_replace("#/\*.*?\*/#si", '', $settings); // get rid of comments to avoid confusion with preg_match
preg_match('#\$databases.*?;#si', $settings, $dbraw); // get the desired part of the string
eval("\$databases = " . $dbraw[0]); // eval() to create the variable
```